# Any interface for building a server in Linux Xubuntu. (not desktop)

Tags: webserver, administration

Is there any interface or program that I could install on my Linux Xubuntu that would help me set up a server using the terminal as little as possible?

Comment: What do you mean "set up a server?"  What do you want your server to do?

Answer (score 3):

Probably your best bet would be to make use of the application [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/index.html).

*excerpt*

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache, DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a system from the console or remotely. See the [standard modules](http://www.webmin.com/standard.html) page for a list of all the functions built into Webmin, or check out the [screenshots](http://www.webmin.com/demo.html).

List of modules:

```
adsl-client             apache                  dnsadmin
bind8                   ipfw                    backup-config
bacula-backup           bandwidth               init
burner                  pserver                 change-user
passwd                  cluster-passwd          cluster-copy
cluster-cron            cluster-shell           cluster-software
cluster-usermin         cluster-useradmin       cluster-webmin
shell                   cfengine                custom
dhcpd                   quota                   mount
dovecot                 fail2ban                fetchmail
file                    fsdump                  filter
frox                    grub                    tunnel
heartbeat               ipfilter                ipsec
inittab                 jabber                  krb5
ldap-client             ldap-server             ldap-useradmin
lilo                    firewall                raid
logrotate               lvm                     mailcap
mon                     majordomo               mysql
sgiexports              exports-nfs4            bsdexports
exports                 hpuxexports             dfsadmin
nis                     net                     xinetd
inetd                   openslp                 pam
phpini                  pap                     ppp-client
pptp-client             pptp-server             format
bsdfdisk                fdisk                   cpan
postfix                 postgresql              lpadmin
proftpd                 procmail                htaccess-htpasswd
qmailadmin              rbac                    mailboxes
proc                    smart-status            telnet
sshd                    stunnel                 samba
at                      cron                    webmincron
sentry                  sendmail                smf
shorewall               shorewall6              package-updates
software                zones                   spam
squid                   sarg                    man
syslog                  syslog-ng               system-status
time                    status                  tcpwrappers
ajaxterm                updown                  usermin
useradmin               vgetty                  wuftpd
webalizer               webminlog               webmin
servers                 acl                     iscsi-client
iscsi-server            iscsi-target            idmapd
```

*Source: http://download.webmin.com/download/modules/standard.txt*

Answer (score 0):

I done some research and I think this is what you need to look at:

- if you prefer working from a GUI based interface [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)
- also you can use this post as a start [GUI for ubuntu server: xfce or xubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305646/gui-for-ubuntu-server-xfce-or-xubuntu-desktop)